# After creating a function I am trying to call it again which isn't working

Tags: python, function

Got my first script working and very excited about it.  Modifying it to work with functions and running into issues.  Appreciate help with this so I can better understand.  As I understand I can define a function and then I can call it again.  So I created a function below "sh_ap_sum".
I'm trying to run that so that it dumps the output of the command to a file.

Then I am calling that function again with "sh_ap_sum(cdp)" and trying to display the output of the file in the terminal window.  Am I completely doing it wrong any hints will be appreciated greatly.  Thank you.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import sys

def sh_ap_sum(ap_sum):

        ipaddr = input('IP:''')
        net_connect =  ConnectHandler(ip = ipaddr,port = 22,username = 'admin',password = 'mypassword',device_type = 'cisco_wlc_ssh')
        net_connect.find_prompt()
        '(Cisco Controller) >'
        output = net_connect.send_command('show ap summary')
        sys.stdout = open('wlccon.txt', 'w')
        net_connect.disconnect()

sh_ap_sum(cdp)

        output = net_connect.send_command('show ap cdp ne all')
        print(output)
```

Comment: Besides the cited duplicate, please look up other resources on passing information into and out of a function.  Also see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks I thought I added all the explanation already in there including the full code, I am a bit confused on what else I should have added here?  Very new to this like less than a day new so this isn't making sense much.  Also checking out that scoping rules link as well.  PS: I have posted this here after spending quit some time trying to utilize multiple other resources online.

Answer (score 0):

`net_connect` is defined in your function. You can't access it after you already called `sh_ap_sum()` on the third-to-last line. At that point, re-indenting and trying to re-enter the function scope is not possible. Plus, you've already called `net_connect.disconnect()` at the end of your function.

You will need to make another connection, or return the output you want from the function itself.

Comment: Thank you makes sense.  I ended up using two commands under the same function and dumped those to a text file which worked.  I still would like to figure out few other things but that is a separate issue.  Thank you for your help.